# Get an ec2 instance name from metadata

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

I need to grab the instance name from EC2 instance for my python script. But stuck how to do that.

My script for other data:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from ec2_metadata import ec2_metadata
import sys
print("Region =  " + ec2_metadata.region)
```

Need something similar to that.

I've tried `virtual_name` but it is not working.

Comment: The name of an Amazon EC2 instance is the value of a Tag with the Key of `Name`. It is not accessible via EC2 Instance Metadata. It will require an API call to the EC2 service.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear how to get instance name?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "instance name"?

If it is the first column in the console, try to get the Tags data with "Name" is the key

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance) to get the Tags and locate the lone with `Name` as key:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance('intance_id')
print(instance.tags)
```

Your instance will also need [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) with permissions to interact with ec2.